# makefile error missing separator error

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am trying to use make with my c program. It's a simple calculator program. I created the makefile but it is not being executed when i run make using the terminal.
here is my make file

```
calculatormade:
\tadd.o sub.o multiply.o divide.o Calculator_Main.o gcc add.o sub.o multiply.o divide.o Calculator_Main.o -o calculatormade
add.o: 
\tadd.c gcc add.c -c
sub.o: 
\tsub.c gcc sub.c -c
multiply.o: 
\tmultiply.c gcc multiply.c -c
divide.o: 
\tdivide.c gcc divide.c -c
Calculator_Main.o:
\tCalculator_Main.c head.h gcc Calculator_Main.c -c
clean:
\trm calculatormade add.o sub.o multiply.o divide.o Calculator_Main.o
```

Comment: Does your `makefile` look like the text you've posted?  Otherwise, please edit your post to use actual tabs and line breaks at the places where you have them in the `makefile`.

Comment: As written your makefile is clearly incorrect. You have a tab then the prerequisites then a space and then the command on the same line.

Comment: As eylam indicates in their answer you want `target: prerequisite\n\tcommand`. See [Rule Syntax](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax).

Answer (score 2):

The tab separator is misplaced. You should put on the first line the taget, colon and the files it is dependent on.
On the second line (that must start with tab) you need to build the build instructions. For exmple:

```
calculatormade: add.o sub.o multiply.o divide.o Calculator_Main.o
<TAB>gcc add.o sub.o multiply.o divide.o Calculator_Main.o -o calculatormade

add.o: add.c
<TAB>gcc add.c -c
```

Comment: Absolutely true but doesn't explain the error. As written the OP makefile would just error terribly.

Comment: Missing separator is the most common make error. It means in general that something is wrong with the Makefile format

Comment: I'm aware of that and as written the OP makefile doesn't have that sort of error. Try it yourself.